# Storing And Working With Dynamic Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, architecture

So, I'm working on an eCommerce application and my customer wants the ability to create categories and products...obviously.  Now, lets say the client will have about 100 categories and 20,000 products.

The client needs the ability to create category properties that make sense for filtering....so, the category Hard Drives might have properties like:

- Capacity
- RPMs
- Form Factor

While the category Projectors might have properties like:

- Brightness
- Contrast Ratio
- Native Resolution

My question is how does one solve the problem of allowing custom properties to be created dynamically, but the ability to use those properties to search, filter and report on?

Creating a seperate table and object for each category isn't possible since I have no idea what categories they will create (i.e. HardDriveProperties, ProjectorProperties).

I thought maybe I could create an extra column in the database and serialize the custom properties as JSON, but that would still require me to either create a specific properties object for each category to deserialize the JSON into or a generic list of ProductProperties....which I think could be pretty expensive to work with.

How are others solving this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Entity-Attribute-Value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) (aka 'open schema') is one way to solve this problem.

The essence of the pattern is that you make columns into rows. Instead of `HardDrive` (and `Projector`) tables that look like this:

```
HardDrive(HardDriveID, Capacity, RPMs, FormFactor)
------------------    
1 1TB 7200 External
```

You have `Category`, `CategoryProperties`, and `CategoryPropertyValues` tables:

```
Category(CategoryID, Description)
--------
1 Hard Drive
2 Projector

CategoryProperties(CategoryPropertyID, CategoryID, Description)
------------------
1 1 Capacity
2 1 RPMs
3 1 FormFactor
4 2 Brightness
5 2 Contrast Ratio
... etc.

CategoryPropertyValues(ItemID, CategoryPropertyID, PropertyValue)
------------------
1 1 1TB
1 2 7200
1 3 External
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a table Product which has a column ProductID.
Create a table ProductAttribute which has these columns: Product (referenced ProductID), Name, Value.

One site I saw had several Value columns, one text and one number, to allow efficiently searching by a range for numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use a relational database, I would probably use something like in the lines of this:

```
Category(Id, Name)
Property(Id, CategoryId, Description)
Product(Id, CategoryId, Name)
ProductsProperties(Id, ProductId, CategoryId, Value)
```

That way, you can define which properties should be available when adding/editing a product that belongs to a specific category and a product could have inifinite properties.

This would be better than just serializing JSON values, because searching/filtering for the serialized values may be really painful. However, this approach does use a relatively normalized database structure and thus may might be slow for a full-text search if you have a lot of products, properties, ...

Answer (score 0):

I think that your last paragraph would be the route that I would go. My main concern would be with the performance of (de)serialization of large numbers of records.